# how do i extract id parameter from an URL using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

`http://localhost:3000/messages/?qr_asset_id=1f6b997464&gts=1627828213`
this is an URL, I need to extract the `qr_asset_id` value from this URL
how do I do this with reactjs

Answer (score 1):

You pull it from the props. `props.match.params.qr_asset_id`

Answer (score 1):

As you're using hooks based on your used tags:

```
const location = useLocation();

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
const paramValue = urlParams.get('qr_asset_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

*check for browser compatibility first*

```
const url = window.location.href // "http://localhost:3000/messages/?qr_asset_id=1f6b997464&gts=1627828213";
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url);

const qrAssetId = searchParams.get("qr_asset_id"); // 1f6b997464
```

[query parameter](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) guide in react-router should help.

There are url-polyfill libraries out there too. You can use them to get the same result.

- [url-polyfill](https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill)
- [whatwg-url](https://github.com/jsdom/whatwg-url)